# Convert backward slash to forward slash in python

Tags: python, ruby, path

Hi 
I have read articles related converting backward to forward slashes.
But sol was to use raw string.

But Problem in my case is :

I will get file path dynamically to a variable 
var='C:\dummy_folder\a.txt'
In this case i need to convert it to Forward slashes.
But due to '\a',i am not able to convert to forward slashes

How to i convert it? OR How  should i change this string to raw string so that i can change it to forward slash

Comment: Where does this string "dynamically" come from? The main place backslash has a special meaning in your Python programs is in your Python source code string literals, which should be static.

Comment: **Why** do you want to convert them?

Comment: On Windows, Python outputs `C:\path\to\file.txt`; however, I desire to run a command in git bash which should be `/c/path/to/file.txt`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't do this. Just use [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) and let it handle everything. You should not explicitly set the forward or backward slashes.

```
>>> var=r'C:\dummy_folder\a.txt'
>>> var.replace('\\', '/')
'C:/dummy_folder/a.txt'
```

But again, don't. Just use os.path and be happy!

Comment: thanks for the ans,but ihave tried os.path, but it wont change backward to forward slash because '\a',\n' will be processed before converting

Comment: Abhishek, you can replace it using the way I showed above, but you should not .

Comment: The poroblem is   there are libraries that CRASAH with  windows path format (even on windows) and we NEED to convert those.

Answer (score 12):

There is also [os.path.normpath](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath)(), which converts backslashes and slashes depending on the local OS. Please see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) for detailed usage info.  You would use it this way:

```
>>> string = r'C:/dummy_folder/a.txt'
>>> os.path.normpath(string)
'C:\dummy_folder\a.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out normpath, however, it only works one way:  Converting forward slashes to back slashes. It doesn't work the other way (back slash to forward slash).  I guess the best way is to assume linux paths and make sure all path strings use forward slashes. Then, call normpath() on the string just before it is used.

Comment: This is for me the best answer. Under Mac OS X, `os.path.normpath` preserves forward slashes, as expected. Under Windows, slashes are converted to backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

Handling paths as a mere string could put you into troubles.; even more if the path you are handling is an user input or may vary in unpredictable ways.

Different OS have different way to express the path of a given file, and every modern programming language has own methods to handle paths and file system references. Surely Python and Ruby have it:

- Python: [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html)
- Ruby: [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html) and [FileUtils](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/FileUtils.html)

If you really need to handle strings:

- Python: string.replace
- Ruby : string.gsub

Answer (score 1):

Raw strings are for string literals (written directly in the source file), which doesn't seem to be the case here. In any case, forward slashes are not special characters -- they can be embedded in a regular string without problems. It's backslashes that normally have other meaning in a string, and need to be "escaped" so that they get interpreted as literal backslashes.

To replace backslashes with forward slashes:

```
# Python:
string = r'C:\dummy_folder\a.txt'
string = string.replace('\\', '/')

# Ruby:
string = 'C:\\dummy_folder\\a.txt'
string = string.gsub('\\', '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 'C:\\dummy_folder\\a.txt'.replace('\\', '/')
'C:/dummy_folder/a.txt'
```

In a string literal, you need to escape the `\` character.

Comment: Thanks for sol, How did u change single backward slashes to 2 backward slashes?

Comment: You need to code it like that with two backslashes. A backslash is a special character, and to get one true backslash in the string literal you need to type two.