# Fix undesired escape sequences in path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a path in a variable like that:

```
path = "C:\HT_Projeler\7\Kaynak\wrapped_gedizw.tif"
```

Which is incorrect because it contains escape sequences:

```
>>> path
'C:\\HT_Projeler\x07\\Kaynak\\wrapped_gedizw.tif'
```

How can I fix the path in this variable so it becomes equivalent to `r"C:\HT_Projeler\7\Kaynak\wrapped_gedizw.tif"` or `"C:/HT_Projeler/7/Kaynak/wrapped_gedizw.tif"`?

I know the topic is common and I investigated many questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297450/convert-backward-slash-to-forward-slash-in-python),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605563/efficiently-convert-backslash-to-forward-slash-in-r) etc.) in here.

**ADD**

Here is my exact script:

```
...
basinFile = self._gv.basinFile
basinDs = gdal.Open(basinFile, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
basinNumberRows = basinDs.RasterYSize
basinNumberCols = basinDs.RasterXSize
...
```

In here `self._gv.basinFile` consists my path. So I cannot put "r" beginngin of `self._gv.basinFile`

Comment: You should try `path = r"C:\HT_Projeler\7\Kaynak\wrapped_gedizw.tif"` instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python)

Comment: I can't. because it comes me as variable like path not directly as "C:\HT_Projeler\7\Kaynak\wrapped_gedizw.tif"

Comment: Where does that variable come from? The person who's creating it is responsible for getting it right.

Comment: @Aran-Fey It does not work for me. I think my question is clear

Comment: @Aran-Fey program that I use. It generates files and assign their path to variable

Comment: Is it possible for you to fix that program?

Comment: @Aran-Fey No, unfortunately

Comment: If you are trying to read the filepaths, why don't you use os.walk or os.listdir(path) to read in the file names, you wouldn't face this problem at that time

Comment: The embedded `\7` is incorrect, it is a bug in whatever created `self._gv.basinFile`.

Answer (score 5):

If you insert paths in Python code, just use raw strings, as other have suggested.

If instead that string is out of your control, there's not much you can do "after the fact". Escape sequences conversion is not injective, so, given a string where escape sequences have already been processed, you cannot "go back" univocally. IOW, if someone **incorrectly** writes:

```
path = "C:\HT_Projeler\7\Kaynak\wrapped_gedizw.tif"
```

as you show, you get

```
'C:\\HT_Projeler\x07\\Kaynak\\wrapped_gedizw.tif'
```

and there's no way to guess surely "what they meant", because that `\x07` may have been written as `\7`, or `\x07`, or `\a`. Heck, any letter may have been originally written as an escape sequence - what you see in that string as an `a` may have actually been `\x61`.

Long story short: your caller is responsible for giving you correct data. Once it's corrupted there's no way to come back.

Comment: Thank you, finally I get a sensible answer. 7 is here project name. I think project name must begin with letter, not number.

Comment: @MustafaUçar - the other answers and comments were because you did not tell the full story first time around and made several edits.

Comment: @MustafaUçar: you may think what you want, but you cannot be sure, and once it's broken, it's broken. The correct thing to do here is to **avoid corrupting data in first place**. Who is that writes that `path = ` statement in first place (or, in your actual code, initializes `self._gv.basinFile`)?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, there is no way to tell whether a character in a path is correct or not without externally checking the actual paths on your computer (and "special character" is not really well-defined; how do you know that the path wasn't `\0x41` which got converted to `A` anyway?)

As a weak heuristic, you could look for path names within a particular editing distance, for example.

```
import os
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as similarity  # or whatever

path_components = os.path.split(variable)
path = ''
for p in path_components:
    npath = os.path.join(path, p)
    if not os.path.exists(npath):
        similar = reversed(sorted([(similarity(None, x, p).ratio(), x) in os.listdir(npath)]))
        # recurse on most similar, second most similar, etc?  or something
    path = npath
```